# FeatureDetector vs. FeatureFinder in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, surf

I'm trying to understand the difference between the [`FeatureDetector`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html) class and the [`FeatureFinder`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/matching.html#detail-featuresfinder) class. I've seen panorama examples written in OpenCV use both of these classes and it appears to be possible to use the SURF algorithm with either one. It was my understanding that the `SURF FeatureDetector` was moved to `/nonfree` because of possible issues with the SURF algorithm, but yet, `FeatureFinder` also can employ the `SURF` algorithm.

What's the difference between these two classes?

Answer (score 2):

FeatureFinder  can use the SURF algorithm because it is implemented using FeatureDetector.
Whichever you use, you are actually getting the same SURF implementation, just different interface.

FeatureFinder  has an interface compatible with the stitching pipeline whereas FeatureDetector has an interface to match the 2d features framework.